# Quran font "KFGQPC Uthmanic" numbers of the ayah

Tags: fonts, arabic-support

Font "KFGQPC Uthmanic Script HAFS" three-digit numbers of the ayah divides between two **u+06dd**. Is there a solution to the problem?

Font **UthmanicHafs1 Ver09** http://fonts.qurancomplex.gov.sa/?page_id=42
Look at the screenshot .

[image]

Comment: link is to removed page

Comment: did you solve your problem? I'am also getting this kind of error!

Comment: the solution is simple, just type the numbers in reverse and it should work.
For example if you want to write 285, just type 582 and it should display the number correctly.
It has got to do something with text rtl or ltr thing.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was solved by updating the font. **UthmanicHafs1Ver13** https://fonts.qurancomplex.gov.sa/wp02/?s=KFGQPC+Uthmanic+Script+HAFS

Comment: I'm still having the same problem with version13

Comment: I'am also facing this problem :(

Comment: the solution is simple, just type the numbers in reverse and it should work.
For example if you want to write 285, just type 582 and it should display the number correctly.
It has got to do something with text rtl or ltr thing.

Answer (score 1):

1   `\u{FC00}`

2   `\u{FC01}`

11  `\u{FC0A}`

100  `\u{FC63}`

...

276 `\u{FD1D}`

Comment: so we need all of this unicode code for every number?

Comment: just need a mapping function e.g. let f= ```(x)=>`\\u{FC${x.toString(16)}}` ```